# Некорректное условие case

Tags: php, логика, case

Попал в просак, и не могу корректно составить условие для case.

```
switch($selld) {
    case $selld < 20:
        $p = 75;
        $lvl = 1;

        break;

    case $selld >= 20:
        $p = 70;
        $lvl = 2;

        break;

    case $selld >= 40:
        $p = 50;
        $lvl = 3;

        break;

    case $selld >= 80:
        $p = 40;
        $lvl = 4;

        break;
}
```

Собственно, обработка значений встает на втором блоке, где `$selld >=20`.
Уже как только не пытался подставлять, но логика сегодня не со мной. 
Так вот, как можно корректно составить условие для блока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch($selld){
    case $selld < 20:
        $p = 75;
        $lvl = 1;

        break;

    case $selld >= 20 and $selld < 40:
        $p = 70;
        $lvl = 2;

        break;

    case $selld >= 40 and $selld < 80:
        $p =50;
        $lvl = 3;

        break;

    case $selld >= 80:
        $p= 40;
        $lvl = 4;

        break;
}
```

Comment: Ну и как правильно отметил @Мелкий, лучше бы в вашем случае использовать конструкцию if-elseif

Answer (score 2):

В блоках case у вас логические выражения. Т.е. выражение в switch сравнивается с булевым значением. Можно, конечно, расписать, что к чему приводится и почему работает так, а не иначе... И на каких граничных случаях код будет вести себя неадекватно для стороннего наблюдателя (проверьте с $selld = 0). Но это всё равно неочевидный костыль.

Или

```
switch (true) {
        case $selld < 20:
...
```

Или, что более очевидно, цепочка if-elseif